# r - trapz doesn't seem to be calculating AUC correctly

Tags: r, roc, auc

I have plotted FPR vs. TPR to make several ROC curves, as shown in [this link](http://imgur.com/6zSyGR1).

However, it seems to me that trapz() is not calculating the correct AUC for the bottom 2 curves. The AUC seems to be larger than the AUCs for the previous plots, yet the calculated AUC is lower.

Can anyone explain to me why this is?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the bottom 2 curves, their axis label go only up to 0.8. I assume you have the FPR/TPR data up to about 0.9. This means that you are missing the part of the AUC between 0.9 and 1. Incidentally, it is the part of the curve that adds most to the AUC. If your true curve was diagonal and stopped exactly at 0.9, you would be missing (1 - 0.9) * 1 - 0.1^2 = 0.09, so your AUC would be 0.41 instead of 0.5.

Make sure you anchor all your FPR and TPR with 0 and 1. It doesn't matter if you have multiple 0s or 1s, just add an additional one in all cases to be safe.